# How to order multiple routes in route.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, routes

I have multiple route controls for multiple actions in my web application.

This actions is called by parameter-

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpecificRoute",
            url: "{BusinessName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Business", action = "OpenPage" }
                );
```

This one is called via `action` name and parameter-

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              name: "ResumeRoute",
              url: "{action}/{PublicResume}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Business", action = "PublicResume" }
                 );
```

And for all default actions I already have one route control by default-

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "WelcomeLedger", action = "Welcome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I have deployed this application on local IIS server.

Now there is something went wrong with `route.config` file, Maybe I am not using routes in proper manner.

So this application shows me `resource not found error` on every action and sometimes it works after cleaning the solution.

How can I use actions without breaking their manner of usage?

**This is my route.config file-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication8 {
    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpecificRoute",
            url: "{BusinessName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Business", action = "OpenPage" }
                );

              routes.MapRoute(
              name: "ResumeRoute",
              url: "{action}/{PublicResume}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Business", action = "PublicResume" }
                 );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "WelcomeLedger", action = "Welcome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );



        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT-**

Default routes not found (`resource not found`) after adding two custom routes above it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your default route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "WelcomeLedger", action = "Welcome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

There is a * before id, it should be `{id}` instead of `{*id}`

Comment: No it was by default there. Note when I remove custom routes. That resource error never comes. But I do have need of both defined routes.

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood you but the default in mvc url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" not url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}", are you sure?

Comment: I don't know why it was there. Yes you were right with default route. Is my route file is said to be correct except this typo?